# issue after magento upgrade to 1.9.3, missing theme on firecheckout page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, css

The problem occurred when i updated magento 1.9.1 to 1.9.3.
The background image in the header and footer are missing. [this is how it looks now after upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zqn8.png)

[image: This is what it should look like]

Could someone help me find away of getting my theme to look right on my checkout page

Answer (score 0):

Try couple things here:

1. Open up the web browser debugging tool. See if there is any 404 or 500 errors on any javascript, CSS, and image files.
2. Try to clear all the cache.
3. Try to reindex all indexes.
4. Try to switch the theme to something else, switch back and do step 2 and 3 again.

It could be the case where the specific theme may not be compatible with 1.9.3. The last vulnerability patch has a 2nd version because it causes some theme to not work properly, so this might be related.

Hope that helps!

Comment: unfortunatly this hasnt helped.